# classification of group of order 12

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When we consider the classification of groups of order 12, we have known it(denote as G) must have either a normal sylow 2 group or normal sylow 3 group.

Assume the sylow 3 group is normal, denote it as N. Assume N is (g). Then Aut(N)=$Z_2$. Aut(N) is generated by $\tau$: g$\to$ $g^2$. G=NH, here H has order 4.

Assume H is $Z_2\times Z_2$. It has two generators, a and b, namely (0,1) and (1,0). For Hom($Z_2\times Z_2$, $Z_2$), there are four cases:

1)$\phi_0:a\to id, b\to id$

2)$\phi_1:a\to \tau, b\to id$

3)$\phi_2:a \to id, b\to \tau$

4)$\phi_3: a\to \tau, b\to \tau$

My question is how we show that the group derived from $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$ are isomorphic? Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I will modify it.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true because in all cases, two of the nonidentity elements of the Klein-Four group are sent to $\tau$, while the third is sent to the identity. This in addition to the fact that any permutation of these nonidentity elements is an automorphism of the Klein-Four group gives that the resulting semidirect products are isomorphic.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks!